# Code inside recieveValue isn't executed in swift ui combine framework

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to download json data from an api and here's the code

```
func fetchTrendingMovies(timeWindow: timeWindowChoices) throws {
    finishedLoading = false
    let urlString = baseUrl + callTypes.trendingMovies.rawValue + timeWindow.rawValue + "?api_key=" + apiKey
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
    guard let url = url else {
        throw apiErrors.invalidUrl
        
    }
    URLSession
           .shared
           .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
           .receive(on: DispatchQueue(label: "any name will do", qos: .background))
           .map(\.data)
           .decode(type: TrendingResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
           .sink { res in
               switch (res) {
               case .finished:
                   print("tmam")
                   self.finishedLoading = true
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("Error: ", error)
               }
           } receiveValue: { [weak self] data in
               print("should happen")
               self?.trendingResponse = data
               guard let resultMovies = data.results else {
                   print("no Movies")
                   return
               }
               self?.trendingMovies = resultMovies
               print(self!.finishedLoading)
           }.store(in: &bag)
```

Problem is, code in sink works perfectly, but the receive value doesn't

Here's the TrendingResponse Model Code

```
struct TrendingResponse: Decodable {
    let page: Int? = nil
    let results: [Movie]? = nil
    let total_pages: Int? = nil
    let total_results: Int? = nil

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        return
    }
}
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Note: I've tried the url on the web and works perfectly

Comment: `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { return }` is not very useful, as well as the *I-don't-care* optionals.

Comment: When I remove them, xcode shouts that that it doesn't conform to decodable'

Comment: There must be another struct `Movie` conforming to `Decodable`. There are countless tutorials how to use `Codable` properly. Please read some of them.